# How to print a Dictionary in a table, when "\t" seperator fails its alignment?

Tags: python

```
Dic = {"War and Peace":60,"Les Miserables":88,"A Tale of Two Cities":75,\
"Jane Eyre":23,"Wuthering Heights":56}
```

This is what I've done and the alignment is just so messy

```
print("Title","Pages",sep="\t\t\t")
for l,v in Dic.items():
    print(l,v,sep="\t\t\t")
```

Comment: **WHAT EXACTLY IS YOUR QUESTION?**

Comment: The bold is strong in this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `format` method to format the string like this

```
myDict = {"War and Peace":60,"Les Miserables":88,"A Tale of Two Cities":75,\
"Jane Eyre":23,"Wuthering Heights":56}
for l, v in myDict.items():
    print "{:20} {:10}".format(l, v)
```

**Output**

```
Jane Eyre                    23
Wuthering Heights            56
War and Peace                60
Les Miserables               88
A Tale of Two Cities         75
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string.format() with field widths is good.  This gives you strings padded in wide fields, padded with blanks that is.

Sometimes I like to use a single table to separate columns in my python code, and pipe the result into the *ix "expand" command.  Expand allows you to convert tabs to an arbitrary number of spaces.  This way, the presentation isn't coded into your Python program.

EG:

```
$ python3 -c 'print(1, "\t", 2)' | expand -30
1                              2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {"War and Peace":60,"Les Miserables":88,"A Tale of Two Cities":75,\
... "Jane Eyre":23,"Wuthering Heights":56}

>>> print ["%20s%4s"%(k, d[k]) for k in d]
['           Jane Eyre  23', 
 '   Wuthering Heights  56', 
 '       War and Peace  60', 
 '      Les Miserables  88', 
 'A Tale of Two Cities  75']
```

if you would like to specify as `left alignment` use

```
>>> print [("%-20s%-4s"%(k, d[k])).strip() for k in d]
['Jane Eyre           23', 
 'Wuthering Heights   56', 
 'War and Peace       60', 
 'Les Miserables      88',
 'A Tale of Two Cities75']
```